# Do non-second-countable spaces have "small" non-second-countable subspaces?

Tags: general-topology

If $X$ is any space which is *not* second-countable, can one find a subspace $Y \subseteq X$ with $|Y| \leq \aleph_1$ which is also *not* second-countable? (Recall that a topological space $X$ is *second-countable* if it has a countable base.)

Note that if we require $|Y| \leq \aleph_0$ there are obvious counterexamples. For example, take $X$ to be the ordinal space $\omega_1$. Since $X$ has uncountably many isolated points, it is not second-countable, but every *countable* subspace is second-countable.

Looking through [the non-second-countable spaces in π-base](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=%7ESecond%20Countable) seems to suggest this is possible, but perhaps the spaces listed there are "too nice".

Comment: If you just want _some_ bound on the size of $Y$, $|Y|\leq\mathfrak{c}^+$ works for rather trivial reasons (the $T_0$ quotient of any second-countable space has cardinality $\leq\mathfrak{c}$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is yes.

There is special terminology and known results along these lines.

If every space with property $P$ has a subspace of size (at most) $\aleph_1$ with property $P$ then one says that property $P$ reflects in size $\le\aleph_1$ spaces.

For example non-metrizability (for compact spaces) reflects in size $\le\aleph_1$ spaces, i.e. 
every non-metrizable (compact Hausdorff) space has a non-metrizable subspace of size $\aleph_1$ (a result of Alan Dow). (Note that in this context $\aleph_1$ and $\omega_1$ are often used interchangeably, he writes 
$\omega_1$ in his paper. Similarly $\aleph_0$, $\omega$ and $\omega_0$ are used interchangeably.)

Recall that $w(X)$ denotes the weight of $X$, i.e. the smallest infinite cardinality of an open base for the topology of $X$.

The answer to your question is yes, see
*Having a small weight is determined by the small subspaces*,
Authors: A. Hajnal and I. Juhász
Journal: Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 79 (1980), 657-658.
http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1980-079-04/S0002-9939-1980-0572322-2/
Abstract: We show that for every cardinal $ \kappa > \omega $ and an arbitrary topological space X if we have $ w(Y) < \kappa $ whenever $ Y \subset X$ and $ \vert Y\vert \leqslant \kappa $ then $ w(X) < \kappa $ as well. M. G. Tkačenko proved this for $ {T_3}$ spaces in [2]. We also prove an analogous statement for the $ \pi $-weight if $ \kappa $ is regular.

Here the property that "reflects" is "having weight $\ge\omega_1$".
If $w(X)\ge\omega_1$ then $w(Y)\ge\omega_1$ for some $Y\subseteq X$ with $|Y|\le\omega_1$. Indeed, if this were not the case, then taking $\kappa=\omega_1$ in the above theorem, we would have that every subspace $Y\subseteq X$ with $|Y|\le\omega_1$ satisfies $w(Y)<\omega_1$ 
(i.e. $w(Y)\le\omega_0$, $Y$ has countable weight, $Y$ is second-countable), and then the conclusion would be that $w(X)<\omega_1$ (i.e. $w(X)\le\omega_0$, $X$ has countable weight, $X$ is second-countable).

For reflection of non-metrizability (with a proof using elementary submodels) see:
*An empty class of nonmetric spaces*, Alan Dow,
Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 104 (1988), 999-1001.
http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1988-104-03/S0002-9939-1988-0964886-9/

And here is a more-or-less random selection about reflecting other properties
(just a few sample links, out of many more).

*On Dow's reflection theorem for metrizable spaces*
Jerry E. Vaughan
TOPOLOGY PROCEEDINGS Volume 22, 1997, 351-360
http://topology.auburn.edu/tp/reprints/v22/tp22123.pdf

*Reflecting point-countable families*, Zoltan T. Balogh
Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 131 (2003), 1289-1296
http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2003-131-04/S0002-9939-02-06621-2/

*Reflecting Lindelöf and converging $\omega_1$-sequences*
Alan Dow, Klaas Pieter Hart
arXiv:1211.2764v2 [math.GN] http://arxiv.org/abs/1211.2764
(Submitted on 12 Nov 2012 (v1), last revised 17 Jul 2013 (this version, v2))

*Reflecting Lindelöfness*
James E. Baumgartner, Franklin D. Tall,
Topology and its Applications
Volume 122, Issues 1–2, 16 July 2002, Pages 35–49
http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166864101001353

*Ideal reflections*
Paul Gartside, Sina Greenwood, and David Mcintyre
TOPOLOGY PROCEEDINGS
Volume 27, No. 2, 2003, Pages 411-427
http://topology.auburn.edu/tp/reprints/v27/tp27203.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Here's a partial result.  In particular, this answers your question in the affirmative for Hausdorff spaces assuming CH, or more generally for Hausdorff spaces if you replace $\aleph_1$ by $\mathfrak{c}$.  (Or slightly more generally, you may replace "Hausdorff" with "no sequence has more than $\mathfrak{c}$ limits".)

**Theorem**: Let $X$ be a Hausdorff space with $|X|>\mathfrak{c}$.  Then there is a subspace $Y\subset X$ of cardinality $\aleph_1$ which is not second-countable.

*Proof*:  We choose a sequence $(x_\alpha)_{\alpha<\omega_1}$ of elements of $X$ by induction as follows: having chosen $x_\beta$ for all $\beta<\alpha$, choose $x_\alpha$ to be a point of $X$ which is not the limit of any sequence in $\{x_\beta\}_{\beta<\alpha}$.  Such a point exists since there are only $\mathfrak{c}$ such sequences, and each has at most one limit.

Now let $Y=\{x_\alpha\}_{\alpha<\omega_1}$; suppose $Y$ is second-countable.  By construction, the set $\{x_\beta\}_{\beta<\alpha}$ is sequentially closed in $Y$ for each $\alpha$, and hence closed in $Y$.  But this means that for each $\alpha$, any basis for $Y$ has an element which contains $x_\alpha$ but does not contain $x_\beta$ for any $\beta<\alpha$.  These sets must be distinct for different values of $\alpha$, so $Y$ cannot be second-countable.

Comment: Thank-you for the partial result. So I guess if one looks for a counterexample, it cannot be a Hausdorff space. (Actually, it's a bit stronger than that, since you're only using that convergent sequences have unique limits, which is a slightly weaker condition than Hausdorffness.)

Comment: In fact, you only need that every convergent sequence has at most $\mathfrak{c}$ limits.  So if you want to find a counterexample assuming CH, it must be a space which has a sequence with more than $\mathfrak{c}$ different limits.